# Do I need to replace the junction box when changing LED downlight

Tags: lighting, led, junction-box, recessed-lighting

I have 4 LED downlights in my bedroom that I want to swap out for some internet enabled ones.
I wasn't the one to install them so I don't know the make/model of them.

I took one out to have a look and they connect like the one shown below (*same white connector and junction box*), but I can't get the junction box out to check a brand or anything.

**Question:** If I get different light with the same connector, could I simply unplug the current ones and replace them without installing a new box, or is that not possible?

[image]

Comment: Maybe, if you [edit] your question to provide a picture of your _actual_ light, including the fixture, the wiring and as much of the box as you can see, someone might recognize it and be able to ID it for you. If you replace it with one from the same manufacturer, there's a _possibility_ that you may be able to replace the fixture without replacing all the control electronics. You'd have to confirm with the manufacturer, though.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's very unlikely to work, even if you do manage to find another one with the same connector.
The box you're looking at is not just a junction box, it's also the power supply for the LEDs - and it's specific to the type and number of LEDs in the fixture.